# Rails: No route matches [POST], but I have the route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to solve an issue. I have this ajax call:

```
class @SectionTable
  constructor: ->
    @table  = $('#section-table')
    @_dnd()

  _dnd: ->
    @table.tableDnD onDrop: (table, row) ->
      data = $.tableDnD.serialize()
      $.ajax
        type: 'POST'
        url: Routes.reorder_admin_sections_path
        data: data

$ -> new SectionTable()
```

The ajax script doesn't launch:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [POST] "/admin/sections/reorder(.:format)"
```

But in my routes:

```
resources :sections, concerns: [:activatable] do
  collection do
    post 'reorder'
  end
end
```

Anche my routes results:

```
reorder_admin_sections POST   /admin/sections/reorder(.:format)                                                       admin/sections#reorder
```

Why???

Comment: Not sure here, but looks like Routes.reorder_admin_sections_path is returning the actual string "/admin/sections/reorder(.:format)".  You have routes defined for "/admin/sections/reorder.html", "/admin/sections/reorder.json" etc. but not with the suffix of (.:format).